# Socket created Enter a message to send : Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN

Tags: php, sockets

Socket created Enter a message to send :
Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\client.php on line 28
Could not send data: [0] The operation completed successfully.

**Server.php** (run on CMD)

```
<?php
    error_reporting(~E_WARNING);
    if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
    {
     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }
      echo "Socket created \n";
    if( !socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0" , 9999) )
    {
      $errorcode = socket_last_error();
      $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
      die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }
      echo "Socket bind OK \n";
    while(1)
    {
      echo "Waiting for data ... \n";
      $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
      echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;
    socket_sendto($sock, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
     }
     socket_close($sock);
    ?>
```

**Client.php** (Run on Browser)

```
<?php
     error_reporting(~E_WARNING);
     $server = '127.0.0.1';
     $port = 9999;
     if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
     {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
     }
      echo "Socket created \n";
     while(1)
     {
        echo 'Enter a message to send : ';
        $input = fgets(STDIN);
        if( ! socket_sendto($sock, $input , strlen($input) , 0 , $server , $port))
     {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
     }
     if(socket_recv ( $sock , $reply , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
     {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
     }
         echo "Reply : $reply";
     }
     ?>
```

when running both of server.php and client.php on cmd work fine, but when the client run on browser its show me like that, how to fix it?

Comment: There is no `STDIN` for a webpage.  You would need a form or other HTML object that would post data to the server process.